# enqueue tinymce editor in customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I'm having a hard time trying to make tiny mce editor work in the wordpress customizer.

It looks like just calling "wp_editor" from my WP_Customize_Control extension doesn't trigger loading of TinyMCE scripts in the customizer.

I've tried to load them manually like in this answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175307/tinymce-is-not-defined-when-not-using-wp-editor

and also tried with `wp_enqueue_script('tiny-mce')` but to no avail.

Here's my render method, nothing fancy:

```
    public function render_content() {

        ?>
        <label>
            <span class="customize-control-title"><?php echo esc_html( $this->label ); ?></span>
            <?php
            $settings = array(
                'media_buttons' => false,
                'quicktags' => false,
                'teeny' => true
            );

            wp_editor($this->value(), $this->id, $settings );
            ?>
        </label>
        <?php
    }
```

Any suggestions on how this should be done right?

Comment: Found out this and it looks like it might be related due to the fact that the accordions in the customizer are moving: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out one solution but using wp_editor in the customizer means opening pandora's box.

Adding `do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');` before creating the editor:

```
do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
wp_editor($this->value(), $this->id, $settings );
```

will have TinyMCE get rendered. However, issues that still remain are:

- updates in the rich text box are saved to the corresponding textarea, however events like "changed" or "keyup" that the wp.customize is watching for to do the postMessage are not triggered by the rich editor but only when changing directly the textarea.
- because of the above, the "Save" button will not get enabled.
- artificial triggering of the "changed" and "keyup" events on the textarea are not caught by wp.customize, hence the update callbacks in the preview area are not called
- once every several customizer loads the tinymce will not be rendered completely, probably due to the way the admin scripts are loaded

Therefore, after much digging on this topic I realized that the wp_editor is not yet ready to be used reliably in other areas than posts editing.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work. See my answer with a conclusive code sample on [workdpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274333/124419).

p.s. I too resorted to calling `do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts')` which is obviously a dirty hack as it includes a bunch of other unnecessary scripts on the customizer page but does the trick awaiting for a more elegant solution..